# SwipeRefresh Doesn't Work On Fragments - API 19

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm currently implementing `swipeRefreshLayout` the problem was, it's still not showing up. I tried to implement some of the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739182/recycler-view-not-scrolling-properly-after-implementing-swipe-to-refresh-layout) ,and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101158/swiperefreshlayout-loader-not-going-up-when-pull-down-android) ,and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858692/swiperefreshlayout-setrefreshing-not-showing-indicator-initially) .

my gradle module: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

Here's my sample xml:`recycler_view`

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/recycler_relative_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/feeds_swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //INFLATE
        mRelativeLayoutRoot = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view,container,false)
                                                       .findViewById(R.id.recycler_relative_root);
    //MAP SWIPE REFRESH
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mRelativeLayoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.feeds_swipe_refresh);

    //MAP RECYCLER VIEW
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRelativeLayoutRoot.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    //RECYCLER VIEW LAYOUT
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    //ORG ADAPTER
        orgListAdapter = new OrgListAdapter(organizationDataList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(orgListAdapter);

    //GET DATA REQUEST
        parseJSONData();

    return recyclerView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            parseJSONData();
        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(R.color.appIntroColorFifth,
            R.color.appIntroColorFourth,
            R.color.appIntroColorOne,
            R.color.appIntroColorTwo);
}
```

Whenever I swipe down, nothing happens, swipe refresh doesn't show up either.
I test this on an actual device running `API 19 (Kitkat)` and `API 23 (Marshmallow)` in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning your `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView()`, not the entire view, so your fragment is only displaying your `RecyclerView`. You shouldn't need to get your root layout at all, just create the view and use it to find the subviews. And make sure you `return` the root view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.feeds_swipe_refresh);

    // Your other create view code here...

    return view;
}
```

And if you really need the root `RelativeLayout` you can just call:

```
mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view;
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I miss that one. But maybe it will work if I `return mRelativeLayoutRoot;` I forgot that it always `return recyclerView;`

Comment: How do I dismiss this thing if it already loaded my data in JSON?

Comment: @RoCk Yes, it should work if you return `mRelativeLayoutRoot` as well. To dismiss the `SwipeRefreshLayout` you should have some sort of callback when you load your JSON data, in that callback you can call `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`.

Comment: Thanks bryan, working on it. It always shows up due to that runnable code.

Comment: @RoCk Oh, right, I forgot to mention that. You should not need the `Runnable` at all, `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` can run on the main thread. I would also suggest putting `setRefreshing(true)` at the top of your `parseJSONData()` method, this way it will start refreshing every time your reload your data. And then you can dismiss it in your callback, like I stated before.

Comment: Is there a way I can slow down this thing? It loads too fast. I can only see it if I pull down.

Comment: @RoCk You mean your data loads too fast? If that is the case, I would have to highly advise against slowing it down. If your data is no longer loading, there is no reason to continue to display a loading prompt.

Comment: I have that in mind. Maybe because I'm doing this on an emulator. Not on actual device. Many Thank you for your help and time.